# nber of rows within a group in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

In order to generate a report in ireport i need this query in oracle 10g.

SCHOOL:

```
SELECT STID,NAME,DEPT,SUM(CHARGE)


STID | PROG  | DEPT | CHARGE
1      1        A      1
2      1        B      2
3      2        A      2
4      2        B      1
5      1        A      2
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
DEPT | PROG | NBER_OF_STID | TOT_CHG
A       1       2             3
        2       1             2
B       1       1             2
        2       1             1
```

this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPT, DISTINCT PROG, COUNT(STID), SUM (CHARGE) TOT_CHG
FROM SCHOOL
GROUP BY DEPT, PROG, STID, CHARGE
```

Help Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?  What's wrong with what you have?  Please don't make us try to guess what problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group by` only the columns that aren't going to be aggregated.
Try this:

```
SELECT DEPT, PROG, COUNT(STID) NBER_OF_STID, SUM (CHARGE) TOT_CHG
FROM SCHOOL
GROUP BY DEPT, PROG
```

Note: in your query you'll always get a tabular view, so results will be like this:

```
DEPT | PROG | NBER_OF_STID | TOT_CHG
A       1       2             3
A       2       1             2
B       1       1             2
B       2       1             1
```

IMHO, the visual formatting should be made in the report itself (ireport)

Comment: @soulemanemoumie, then why not accept the answer? it will give me rep, and help others know that this answer is helpful